# Xor starting with the significant bit

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, xor, bit

```
int a= 21;//10101
int b = 269;//100001101
```

`a^b` will do

```
    10101
100001101
---------
100011000
```

but I want to do

```
10101
100001101
---------
001011101
```

Is there any way to do it without changing the original numbers?

Comment: You could use left-bit-shift on a?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can shift `a` to align it with `b` on the left. The sample code below works with your example but does not properly handle overflows etc. It should give you a starting point though.

```
int a = 21;
int b = 269;

int shift = Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(a) - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(b);

int c = (a << shift) ^ b;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(c)); // 1011101
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a left bit shift on `a`, which will add `0`s to the end of `a`, which won't change the value of your `XOR`:

```
//Calculate how far to shift
int shiftLength = Integer.toBinaryString(b).length() - Integer.toBinaryString(a).length();

//Apply shift
int aShited = a << shiftLength;

//Execute
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(aShifted^b));
```